# Magento website offline after removing base_url (cloudflare)

Tags: magento, cloudflare

I'm running my Magento shop with Cloudflare. Everything was working fine, until I was stupid enough to remove the unsecure and secure base_url in the admin config section. After this, I get a cloudflare 520 error: "web server is returning an unknown error".

Thinks I checked or did
- error log of my webserver is empty. So I presume there are no errors
- In phpmyadmin I changed the records base_url in core_config_data
- removed magento cache

There are no Magento error logs (exception.log and system.log) so I presume I haven't turned error logging on. Is there any posibility I can turn on error logging in phpmyadmin, since I cannot access the admin panel.

Besides the error logging, is there anyone who knows what could be wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Find `errors/local.xml.sample` file in Magento root directory and rename it to `local.xml`.

Comment: local.xml is already present.

@Enigmativity: you're right. This topic can be closed. I will open a new one on magento.stackexchange.com